# fadeToggle method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm experiencing behavior from the fadeToggle() method that I am confused by.  I was wondering if someone could explain it to me.  I'm using this to show/hide a search bar when clicking the #search-bar element:

```
  $("#search-bar").click(function () {
    $("input.search-field").fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

but it only appears for a moment, and then it disappears again.  However, if I add this bit :

```
let searchIcon = document.getElementById("search-bar");
let searchField = document.querySelector("input.search-field");
```

then it works as expected.  Could someone please explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share your code where you are having trouble?

Comment: This is the element:

<img id="search-bar" src="http://XXXXXXXXXXX.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/search-glass.png">

Comment: Can you post all of your HTML?  This fiddle seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/5v0dn8ab/

Comment: Well, that might be kind of difficult because this is a wp site and a lot of the html is only generated through wp functionality.  The code does work when I define the two variables, but I just want to know why it needs those to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` elements are inline by default , which fadeToggle() generally has difficulties with. can you try making you're `<img>` element `display:inline-block`.

Also remove any transitions on the image such as:

```
transition:.5s ease-in-out;
```

The above 2 stated are known issues.

Comment: Nope, still not making a difference unfortunately.

Comment: @RRhodes can you make a minimal demo :- https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Something I just noticed though:  I put a console.log in the jq function, and it logs it twice in the console, which might explain why it's appearing and then disappearing.

Comment: @RRhodes yup , sounds like that the issue

Comment: Oh I think I got it!  The event was propagating through the element hierarchy.  e.stopImmediatePropagation() seemed to fix it.